# How to query polymorphic relationships with different fields in Laravel

Tags: eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-10

I have an `Account` model that has a `Contact` relation. The `Contact` relation can represent different entities: `Customer` or `Employee`.

```
//Account Model
public function contact(): MorphTo
{
    return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'contactidtype', 'contactid');
}

//Customer Model
public function account(): MorphOne
{
    return $this->morphOne(Account::class, 'contact', 'contactidtype', 'contactid');
}

//Employee Model
public function account(): MorphOne
{
    return $this->morphOne(Account::class, 'contact', 'contactidtype', 'contactid');
}
```

Both of these entities has its own table with different fields for name:

`Customers` has a field named `cust_name`.
`Employees` has a field named `emp_name`.

Is there a way to solve this without changing the database tables themselves?

The below code doesn't work because there's not an `emp_name` column in the `Customers` table no and no `cust_name` field in the `Employees` table.

```
Account::where('contact_type', 'Customer')
        ->whereHas('contact', function (Builder $q) use ($search) {
            $q->where('cust_name', 'ILIKE', "%{$search}%");
        })
    ->orWhere('contact_type', 'Employee')
        ->whereHas('contact', function (Builder $q) use ($search) {
            $q->where('emp_name', 'ILIKE', "%{$search}%");
        });
```